# Appending multiple samples of a column into dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have n (length) values in a *spark* column. I want to create a *spark* `dataframe` of k columns (where k is number of samples) and m rows (where m is sample size). I tried using `withColumn`, it is not working. `Join` by creating unique id will be very inefficient for me.

e.g. Spark column has following values :

102
320
11
101
2455
124

I want to create 2 samples of fraction 0.5 as columns in data frame.

So sampled data frame will be something like

```
sample1,sample2

320,101

124,2455

2455,11
```

Let df has a column `UNIQUE_ID_D`, I need k samples from this column. Here is the sample code for k = 2

```
var df1 = df.select("UNIQUE_ID_D").sample(false, 0.1).withColumnRenamed("UNIQUE_ID_D", "ID_1")

var df2 = df.select("UNIQUE_ID_D").sample(false, 0.1).withColumnRenamed("UNIQUE_ID_D", "ID_2")

df1.withColumn("NEW_UNIQUE_ID", df2.col("ID_2")).show
```

This wont work since `withColumn` can not access `df2` column.

There is only way to `join` df1 and df2 by adding sequence column(join column) in both df's.

It is very inefficient for my use case since if I want to take 100 samples, I need to join 100 times in a loop for a single column. I need to perform this operation for all columns in original df.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: please update with your tried code and sample inputs and desired output.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan : Please find the edited question.

Comment: can you update with sample input and desired output as well. :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Please find the sample input and desired output.